# Xpages open url in XPiNC or Web

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am using then new NavigationBar control to control a series of applications. Using the basicLeafNode I have this in the href:

```
var prefix:String = "";
if (@ClientType() == "Web")
{prefix = "https:xxx/"}
else
{prefix = "notes:xxx"}

url = prefix + "path/databsase.nsf?OpenXpage";
url
```

This works fine except in XPiNC I want the link to replace the tab, not open a new window. How can I do this?

===================================================
To clarify, I want the target to replace the current tab, not open a new one. While primarily a web app, the users will access it from XPiNC.

In the onClick event of the NavigationBar I have this in CSJS:

```
window.open('notes://<server>/common/db.nsf/xpHome.xsp?OpenXpage','_self')
```

Just trying to get this to replace the current tab in XPiNC. It opens a new tab. Shouldn't it replace this tab?

Comment: By window.open you ask for opening new tab. Did you try window.location? https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-window-location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brian - in XPiNC the URL is /xsp/path/database.nsf if you are going to do it manually you have to adjust for the XPiNC environment.

Comment: Mark, I clarified my question above.

Comment: I have given up on using XPiNC. It's like what Steve Jobs said about Blue-Ray: it is a big old bag of hurt.

Answer (score 1):

In the XSP Properties there is a setting on the General tab for Window behavior for the Notes client.[image: XSP properties]